# automatic trigger to update records in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm receving data into mysql table from ETL tool

Here is the table

user

```
id username latestlogdate
1   a        2016-11-05 15:52:00 
2   b        2016-11-05 15:52:00
3   c        2016-07-25 15:00:00
4   d        2016-07-24 03:15:00
```

In this table 3rd and 4th records are fine because they are coming correct. But sometime some records like 1 and 2 comes with some future dates.

There is not problem in ETL.

Here's the flow..

csvfiles---->ETL----->Mysqltable

These future dates comes in files. Files I cant change.

So I would like to ask is there any trigger option so that I could update records like this with future date to current date.

My question is, if any record arrives in table with future latestlogdate, that should be automatically updated to current date.( The day they arrives in the table)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have some Event related links off my profile page. So there is that route as opposed to triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can create a trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `MyDatabase`.`MyTriggerName` BEFORE INSERT
ON MyDatabase.MyTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if new.latestlogdate > now() then
      new.latestlogdate = now()
    end if
END;
```

XaV